# How to pass vargar argument to String.format in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arguments

I'm not able to find how to pass a vararg argument directly to another function (String.format) that takes also a vararg argument.

I have a method in which I want to call String.format with variable arguments:

```
fun execute(userId: UserId, action: Action, vararg  arg: Int){
        dataRepository.logAction(userId, String.format(action.log, arg))
    }
```

action.log can be for example "text: %d".

And I'm calling the function like that:

```
execute(UUID.randomId(), Action.MyAction, 13)
```

I'm not able to pass 'arg' to String.format, this gives me:

`Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b91ec3ba, java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService@a1f90c24] Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)`

Which is normal because "arg" is actually considered as a table. So I tried the spread operator:

```
fun execute(userId: UserId, action: Action, vararg  arg: Int){
        dataRepository.logAction(userId, String.format(action.log, *arg))
    }
```

But this does not work either.

Could you indicate me the solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun execute(userId: UserId, action: Action, vararg arg: Int){
  val arr = arg.toTypedArray()
  val format = "Text: " + List(arr.size) { "%d" }.joinToString(", ")
  dataRepository.logAction(userId, String.format(format, *arr))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! You actually pointed me to the right solution with "toTypedArray".
Be carreful, in your above example, you used "list.size" instead of "arr.size". Again much more simple: `dataRepository.logAction(userId, String.format(action.log, *arg.toTypedArray()))`

Comment: @AlexandreHerbreteau Quote 'more simple' – this true and not true. If you have vararg and you want all vararg items processed you have to take that into account in creating a specific format string for the count of arguments. If you have say two interpolation placeholder (two '%d' for example) in your format, but three items in the vararg, only the first two will log. Hence my version with constructing a format string, which will log any count of arguments. If you are sure to only have two, then it would be probably wise to have two separate arguments instead of the vararg.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working making an extra private wrapper function.

Here is my example:

```
class Test {

  fun printStuff(s: String, vararg args: Int) {
    val list: List<String> = listOf(s) + args.map { it.toString() }
    printStuffVararg(list)
  }

  private fun printStuffVararg(args: List<String>) {
    val ss = String.format("s: %s, args: %s %s", *args.toTypedArray())
    println(ss)
  }
}

fun main() {
  Test().printStuff("hello", 1, 2)
}
```

I think the key is `*args.toTypedArray()`

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, you are right, *args.toTypedArray() is the solution, I missed it !